# lag() with group_by between current and last observation in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

Edit: I found the solution with na.locf().

```
data <- 
  data %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  arrange(wave) %>%
  mutate(weight.io = na.locf(weight)) %>%
  mutate(lag_weight = weight - lag(weight.io)
```

I have a dataset below.

```
set.seed(42000)
data <- data_frame(
  country = sample(letters[1:20], size = 100, replace = TRUE),
  weight = round(runif(100, min = 48, max = 90)))

data <- data %>%
  group_by(country)  %>%
  arrange(weight) %>%
  mutate(wave = seq_along(weight))

n_rows <- nrow(data)
perc_missing <- 10
data[sample(1:n_rows, sample(1:n_rows, round(perc_missing/100 * n_rows, 0))), c("weight")] <- NA
```

I would like to obtain the difference between one country's current "weight" and the last observed "weight for each wave.
For country "a" wave 5, I want the value to be 69 - 65 (last observed weight at wave < 5).
And for wave 8, 82(weight at wave 8) - 69(weight at wave 5).

[image]

My approach was the one below, but it didn't work.

```
data <- 
  data %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  arrange(wave) %>%
  mutate(lag_weight = weight - lag(weight, default = first(weight, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Thank you!

Comment: (1) You are generate random data, it is nearly guaranteed that we will produce different data, so we cannot reproduce whatever you are seeing. Since you say there are problems, it helps to provide actual versus expected output, and this requires that we have the same starting data. Please use `set.seed` to set the seed before generating random data. (2) *"It didn't work"*, why? Does it emit an error or warning? Are the actual numbers wrong? (3) Have you tried `mutate(lag_weight = c(0, diff(weight)))`?

Comment: (1) I put set. seed. (2) It doesn't emit any error. The calculated value doesn't consider the command lag(weight, default = first(weight, na.rm = TRUE)), which I want to bring the last to one observation value. (3) didn't solve the problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: (4) *"for each wave"* might suggest adding `wave` to the `group_by`, is that not the case?

Comment: I posted a picture to be specific about the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a combination of `diff` (instead of `lag`, though that could work just as well) and more important `tidyr::fill` (or `zoo::na.locf`, not demonstrated):

BTW, `na.rm=` is not an argument for `first`, I've removed it.

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # fill
data %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  tidyr::fill(weight) %>%
  filter(country == "a") %>%
  mutate(lag_weight = weight - lag(weight, default = first(weight)))
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
# # Groups:   country [1]
#    country weight  wave lag_weight
#    <chr>    <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
#  1 a           54     1          0
#  2 a           55     2          1
#  3 a           65     3         10
#  4 a           65     4          0
#  5 a           69     5          4
#  6 a           69     6          0
#  7 a           69     7          0
#  8 a           82     8         13
#  9 a           82     9          0
# 10 a           85    10          3
```

The issue here is that `weight` is over-written with the LOCF (last-observation carried forward) value instead of preserving the `NA` values. If that's important, then you can make another `weight` variable for temporary use (and remove it):

```r
data %>%
  mutate(tmpweight = weight) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  tidyr::fill(tmpweight) %>%
  filter(country == "a") %>%
  mutate(lag_weight = tmpweight - lag(tmpweight, default = first(tmpweight))) %>%
  select(-tmpweight)
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
# # Groups:   country [1]
#    country weight  wave lag_weight
#    <chr>    <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
#  1 a           54     1          0
#  2 a           55     2          1
#  3 a           65     3         10
#  4 a           NA     4          0
#  5 a           69     5          4
#  6 a           NA     6          0
#  7 a           NA     7          0
#  8 a           82     8         13
#  9 a           82     9          0
# 10 a           85    10          3
```

FYI, you can use `c(0, diff(weight))` instead of `weight - lag(weight)` for the same effect. Since it returns length of 1 shorter (since it is the gap between each value), we prepend a `0` here:

```r
data %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  tidyr::fill(weight) %>%
  filter(country == "a") %>%
  mutate(lag_weight = c(0, diff(weight)))
```

(The `filter(country == "a")` is purely for demonstration to match your example, not that it is required for this solution.)